# Do we need to be worried about a baby climbing out of her bed at night?

Tags: bedroom

My baby girl is turning 10 months old. It could potentially stand up on her toes and reach over her bed's fence. Our bed looks like this,

[image]

We have set it to the lowest possible position.

Do we need to prepare thick blanket around this baby bed in case it climbs out and falls over?

Comment: If someone here suggested it’s not a concern and then it happened, that would not be good at all. You should take whatever precautions you feel are necessary. Parents know their children best.

Answer (score 2):

Babies are gonna figure out how to climb, and they're gonna fall down. Best thing you can do is provide a soft spot to land because no matter how tall you make the crib they're gonna find a way to fall out of it at least once.